# How to convert rtp packet payload bytes to any audio data?

Tags: java, udp, sip, rtp

I am making a project in java without using any third party libraries. I have successfully established an udp connection using the `DatagramSocket`. Then I started communicating using the sip protocol. I have successfully passed the registration and invitation stage. This is how I got the host and port to which the audio data stream will be transmitted. Then I successfully established a connection to the new address using `DatagramSocket`. And i began to receive data in the form of rtp packets. I managed to successfully get the following data from the package: Payload type (in my case 8 or PCMA), Timestamp, Sequence number and payload data (byte array). Now I want to process the received data so that I can use it in the future. That is, save to disk, convert to any other audio format at will, play audio, and so on. I can't figure out what exactly needs to be done with the byte array received from the packet.

Let's say for a start I want to save the received data to a file in the `AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_FLOAT` 8000.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 160 bytes / frame format. What do I need to do for this?

Comment: You need to extract the RTP payload and apply an ALAW decoder (which is a simple lookup table) to get the PCM bytes. Here's a C# version that I imagine you can easily use with Java, https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/blob/master/src/app/Media/Codecs/G711Codecs.cs#L190.

Comment: I am trying to take advantage of the example you suggested. Found the code where this table is used. 
https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/blob/master/src/app/Media/Codecs/AudioEncoder.cs#L138
 I cannot figure out how to correctly map the bytes from the array received in the packet to this table. In the example, I see that the byte value is used as the array index. But in my case, I get positive and negative numbers (for example -43) in payload. Tell me, did I read the payload incorrectly or do I need to process each byte somehow before matching it with the table element?

Comment: The index to the ALAW table is a byte which is not signed. You get back a signed 16 bit PCM sample which is what a lot of sound API's expect to drive a speaker. In other words you supply a one byte ALAW encoded sample and get back a two byte PCM sample. Typically the two byte output is treated as signed 16 bit (short) but sometimes it needs to be converted to a float between 0.0 and 1.0. It all depends on the sound API you want to feed the PCM samples to.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [example](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/blob/master/src/app/Media/Codecs/G711Codecs.cs) by [Aaron Clauson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75658/aaron-clauson) I solved my problem. The byte array from the packet must be converted according to the proposed scheme. I made a working [example](https://gist.github.com/kepocnhh/1d7973bd25bfcdbabe6ecde6d98fd264) of how this might look in Kotlin.

An [example](https://gist.github.com/kepocnhh/8a0ac516f9c727ea7f5f4a8c6f23fbfa) of how to get data from a raw rtp package.

If you glue the resulting arrays in the correct order (by `sequenceNumber`) and no duplicates, then you can, for example, write this to a WAV file using `javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream`, as in the [example](https://gist.github.com/kepocnhh/2e652f8c4cf836c4f9efe988924f15a3).

A simplified [example](https://gist.github.com/kepocnhh/bb4ed28bf9ce68e55183316a7546e981) of how you can play a stream of sound in real time on an Android. And a simplified [example](https://gist.github.com/kepocnhh/693dbda1758da523b56a90e7a5b37568) of how you can send sound from a microphone to a server.